# AWS Rekognition - Search all faces in an image against collection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I have created a collection of images which are all faces of individuals. Now my requirement is to take an image which has multiple people in it and find people in this images against the created collection.

However SearchFacesByImage API picks up only 1 faces from the input image and it doesn't help my case.

If I try to again index the image with multiple people , it generates different faceid of faces as against the faceid from individual photo.

Is there any approach which I can use to meet my requirement?

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: SearchFacesByImage API takes only one face from the input image and searches against the collection. I want to search all the faces in the input image against the collection.

Answer (score -3):

You need to be using indexFaces. That will return all the faces in the image that are detectable.Save them in your db so you can reference the image the faces belong to.

IndexFaces will put all the faces into your specified collection which aws stores.
You can then do searchFaces passing in any of the FaceIds in your collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not want to index the faces to collection. The collection is ready with all the faces and now I am receiving an image which has multiple faces. Hence my ask is , does searchFaces API provide capability to detect multiple faces against a collection?

Comment: No it doesn't. It takes a single FaceId for searchFaces or the largest face found if you use SearchFacesByImage. A workaround might be index the faces and then searchFaces for each and the delete your new input image faces as I see you do not want them in the collection.

Comment: Thanks. So what I am going to approach now is that I will use detectFaces to find the face details in the input Image. Looping through number of faces present(based on detectFaces) and after every iteration , will blur the face that was earlier detected and again perform SearchFacesByImage operation.